# Windows 8 - QT GUI Sink Windows don't open

Tags: windows-8.1, gnuradio-companion

[console window for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asvb2.jpg) I'm kind of new to GNURadio, and I installed "GNURadio 3.7" .

I'm trying to generate a 1 GHz signal, and then saw the generated signal on screen using "QT Gui Frequency Sink".

When I try to run the block diagram, it works, but GUI window does not open, it does not show anything.

I tried 2 block diagrams, which I'm including in attachment. [first block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEDBN.jpg) [console window for first block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asvb2.jpg) [second block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKAtk.jpg) [console window for second block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl7Ie.jpg)

I tried a simple block diagram, I simply generated a signal and then connect it to the "QT Gui Frequency Sink". ("gnuradio_deneme.JPG")

And I tried a second block diagram I took from a youtube video, because I thought maybe I did something wrong with the parameters or connections. ("gnuradio_psk_mod_deneme.JPG")

Can you tell me what is my problem, did I not install a driver or something?

Comment: When you run the flowgraph do you see any errors in the console/terminal? Which Linux distribution do you use and which version? How did you install gnuradio and what is the output of `gnuradio-config-info --version`?

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with Windows and probably can't help here. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60854284/edit) your question and add the above information there. Do you see any errors in the console (the bottom left window)?

Comment: I don't see any error in terminal. I'm adding that screenshot as attached. I'm using Windows 8, I installed from here "http://www.gcndevelopment.com/gnuradio/downloads.htm" , and I used "v3.7.9.2/v1.1.1" for 64-Bit Any CPU .

Comment: @VasilVelichkov , only this lines on the command window: "Showing: "C:\Users\K52J\Documents\psk_mod_deneme.grc"

Generating: 'C:\\Users\\K52J\\Documents\\top_block.py'

Executing: C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7\gr-python27\python.exe -u C:\Users\K52J\Documents\top_block.py

Using Volk machine: sse4_2" I am guessing there is no error

Comment: Your screenshots shows only the flowgraph and does not include the console output. Provide e a screenshot of the whole screen after running the flowgraph and look at the bottom left corner.

Comment: I added the console windows in the question attachments, my screen is not big enough, so I could not get a screenshot of both console and block diagram at once. Sorry for that

Comment: Why did you choose the oldest version? Try installing one of the newer versions, maybe it's a bug that has already been solved in the next versions.

Comment: Because, when I tried the newest version, I clicked gnuradio-companion , and command window pops up and closes. I could not open the GNURadio. But when I tried with 3.7.9.2 . I opened Gnuradio without any errors. But , I'm now getting an error with QT Sink Windows. If I try to use newest version, I could not get to open the Gnuradio. But , I can try 3.7.10 , 3.7.11 , 3.7.12 , 3.7.13 etc. , I did only get problems with 3.8.0.0 version

Comment: I installed 3.7.13.5 , and problem is solved. Thank you so much for this solution @VasilVelichkov